# Blacklisting only a few senders from Gmail's "Forward a copy of incoming mail" feature

Tags: gmail, spam-prevention, email-forwarding, anonymous

I have two Gmail accounts, one trusted and one for "untrusted" websites.

98% of the "untrusted" websites are actually nice, they don't send me any spam, all of the emails they send are actually important (hotel booking notifications, replies to comments, etc). So I have set my untrusted account to forward all emails to my trusted account.

Now how to deal with the 2% of spammers? In my untrusted account, I filtered them to be deleted directly, but even though, they are forwarded to my trusted account :-(

How to prevent these few messages from being forwarded?
*Note: I don't want to log into my "untrusted" account more than twice a year.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can forward all incoming messages via the `Forwarding and POP/IMAP` settings tab. But you can also forward messages by creating a filter. Unfortunately, there's no way that I know of to order the filters and stop processing the remaining filters if an email matches certain criteria.

I have started using aliases for each website, such as `myaddress+twitter@gmail.com` and `myaddress+facebook@gmail.com`. I use these aliases in the `To` field of the filters to apply the correct labels etc.

If you have the ability to change your email address on the sites of the 'spammers' to something like `myaddress+spam@gmail.com`, you can create a filter that applies to all emails sent to `-myaddress+spam@gmail.com` (negative filter) and forward these messages to your trusted account.

**Edit:**
If you don't have the ability to change your email address, you can create a filter that filters out all emails that don't originate from a spam site. You can use a filter on the `From` field that looks like `-@site1.com AND -@site2.com`. It translates to "all emails that are not from site1.com and also not from site2.com".

Comment: The "Edit" part of your post is exactly the trick I was looking for! Thanks a lot :-)